# what's the BestPractice for Docker logging?

Tags: docker, logging, deployment, logstash

Im using docker with my Web service.

when I deploy using Docker, loosing some logging files (nginx accesslog, service log, system log.. etc)

Cause, docker deployment system using down and up container architecures.

So I thought about this problem.
LoggingServer and serviceServer(for api) must seperate!

using these, methods..

First, Using logstash(in elk)(attaching all my logFile) .
Second, Using batch system, this batch system will moves logfiles to otherServer on every midnight.

isn't it okay?

I expect a better answer.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways for logging which most the admin uses for containers

1 ) mount log directory to host , so even if docker goes up/down logs will be persisted on host.

2) ELK server, using logstash/filebeat for pushing logs to elastic search server with tailing option of file, so if new log contents it pushes to server.

3) if there is application logs like maven based projects, then there are many plugins which pushes logs to server

4) batch system , which is not recommended because if containers dies before mid-night then logs will be lost.